# Customizing Android TV Interfaces With LeanBack Support Library

Tags: android, customization, android-tv, leanback

The leanback support library for Android TV projects seems like a good effort to standardize TV experiences. However, I find it a bit too rigid and restricts customization beyond minor ones like color schemes, etc.

My question: what is the best, most efficient way to customize screens such as the DetailsFragment without rewriting the key parts of the leanback framework?

**Background Information**

The default detail screen looks like this: [image]

Some things I would like to be able to do:

1. Place one or two additional views below the DetailsOverViewRow
   (image, title/description, action buttons) that shows extra info
   unique to our app's design (for instance an emoji reactions panel
   and movie credits panel - mostly a thumbnail image and name text
   view of movie creators)
2. Correctly crop the card thumbnail image to fit entirely in its image view. The image is currently clipped, unlike in the browser screen card view where it fits into the card view nicely. The library's [xml
   layout file](https://github.com/kingargyle/adt-leanback-support/blob/master/leanback-v17/res/layout/lb_details_overview.xml) defines a rather small [container size](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/frameworks/support/v17/leanback/res/values/dimens.xml) (fixed
   height of 274dp), and that is probably why the image is not
   properly cropped

**What I've Tried**

Extend `DetailsOverViewRowPresenter` to be able to inflate a custom XML file that defines the additional views. Unfortunately, this class hides its key initializer method, `createRowViewHolder->private initDetailsOverview(ViewHolder vh)`, so I would have to duplicate such hidden yet key methods, which to me defeats the point of subclassing. Is there a better way than to recreate such code? 
NOTE: this approach might be similar to one posted in this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653555/adding-progressbar-to-detailsoverviewrow-on-android-tv) but OP didn't go into further detail.

Comment: for number 1, I made a copy of Presenter provided from android leanback library (AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter class), edit some parts including xml, and I use my class instead of the official from leanback. but I am using FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter. it's still similar, I guess

Comment: If you have solved this, can you please share your solution?

Comment: @khateeb please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I ended up not implementing the details screen. But it looks like the updated leanback library now supports some level of customization. The [google-samples leanback project](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) on github is a decent starting place. For example: [`VideoDetailsFragment`](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/VideoDetailsFragment.java) subclasses the `DetailsFragment`.

Additionally, other customization possibilities discussed in this [medium post](https://medium.com/@Marcus_fNk/building-an-android-tv-app-part-1-7f59b3747446) are worth noting

Comment: I have gone through the sample. It shows how to modify inside of the overview presenter. I also wanted to know how to modify outside of it. Could you answer this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473310/leanback-detailfragment-fullwidthdetailsoverviewrowpresenter-customization