# Leanback DetailFragment FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter customization

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to customize the `FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter` in the Leanback `DetailFragment`. [image: Leanback Sample]

Three things I want to accomplish are:

1. Getting the `Action`s from top to below of the overview.
2. Reducing the height of the overview so that it the related movies can be seen without scrolling down.
3. The background image and the space it occupies at the top of the overview should be gone. The screen should start like the one above.

The end result should be like this:[image: Dove detail]

I already know how to modify inside the overview. How should I modify outside of it?

Comment: how did you achived this ?

Comment: A better way to start implementing the desired UI might be to start from `DetailsOverviewRowPresenter` (keep in mind that it is deprecated) and then modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are moving around the key views of this screen, it sounds like you might have to ditch the current implementation altogether and create your own custom view from scratch. By moving the buttons to the bottom and the detail image (seems like you're moving it to the right side of the description text), you're making it less and less justifiable to even subclass DetailFragment. The developers of Leanback were probably intentional about limiting customizing the interfaces too much as they want a consistent experience for different apps.

I would create a new layout file and load it up on your subclass of DetailsFragment (or DetailsPresenter), depending on your architecture.

You might find inspiration in this [tuenti tv sample](https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/1465) and [part two of Marcus Gabilheri's](https://medium.com/@Marcus_fNk/building-an-android-tv-app-part-2-824766c1ddbe) customization series

Answer (score 1):

- Create Row List Fragment
- In 1st Row create a Rowpresenter that fits your design with buttons
- In other row/s add ListRowPreesenter